# Which three AEM jar names will start AEM in author mode?

Tags: aem, sling, aem-6

```
Which three AEM jar names will start AEM in author mode? (Choose three.) 
A. quickstart-4502.jar
B. cq5-author-p4502.jar
C. aem-publish.jar
D. cq5-author-4502.jar
```

I found this question on web. Is this question is valid?. After reading the AEM 6.0/6.1/6.2 docs, I didn't see any restriction about naming jars(expect containing phrases "author","publish",which will be used for taking runmode at worst case). Could anyone explain if there is any?

Comment: As per my understanding name of jar doesn't matter if we start the instance from 1)sling.properties file 2)using jvm arguments using -r option 3)start script specifying publish mode.

Comment: They meant starting AEM in author mode for the first time by clicking on it. In which case there is no sling.properties file and no start script (pbly you can set up a start script) I am not aware of step 2 that you mentioned. Step 1 is not a valid way to change between author and publisher. You shouldn't change between author and publish modes once you set up an instance.

Comment: @RidingCave this is actually a question from an AEM certification exam and stackoverflow is not the right place for that kind of question. Besides, testing this is extremely easy if you have access to an AEM jar.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

https://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/aem/6-2/deploy.html

"The default install (an author instance on localhost:4502) can be changed simply by renaming the jar file before launching it for the first time. The naming pattern is:
`cq-<instance-type>-p<port-number>.jar`"

**A**. quickstart-4502.jar starts in author (default behavior)

**B**. cq5-author-p4502.jar starts in author (explicitly set to author)

C. aem-publish.jar starts in publish (explicitly set to publish)

**D**. cq5-author-4502.jar starts in author (explicitly set to author)